# Unable to clear the Text box when using Page Methods in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, pagemethods

I have been struggling with .net PageMethods. I have a text box and would like to clear it if the value returned from database call is invalid or its not in the table, now there is a javascript that shows the popup message but fails to clear the field. Here is my code.

```
aspx code:
      asp:TextBox name="LoanNumber" ID="LoanNumber" runat="server" size="18" 
     style="font-size: 9pt"       ValidationGroup="requiredCheck" 
     onchange="javascript:SetFocus();loanCheckup();resetOnChange();" MaxLength="10" 
    ToolTip="Enter a Loan Number"  AutoPostBack="false"></asp:TextBox>

  <asp:RequiredFieldValidator   ID="reqLoanNumExists" runat="server"          ControlToValidate="LoanNumber" Display="Dynamic" 
    ErrorMessage="Required Loan Number"
     SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="requiredCheck">Required!     </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="reqLoanNumber"
 ControlToValidate="LoanNumber" ValidationExpression="\d+"    Display="Static"             
   EnableClientScript="true"    SetFocusOnError="true" 
          ErrorMessage="Accepts Numbers Only!"    runat="server">
       </asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

Page method (code behind)
  [WebMethod]
     public static string getRowValue(string loanNum)
      {

```
    string result = "";
    string tmpResultPass = "";
    string tmpResultFail = "";
 // doing all db connections here 
     try
        {
            if (cmdGetLoanNum.Connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                cmdGetLoanNum.Connection.Open();
            }

            tmpResultPass = cmdGetLoanNum.ExecuteScalar().ToString();

            tmpResultPass = tmpResultPass + "Is Valid";
            return   tmpResultPass ;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string msg = ex.StackTrace.ToString();
             tmpResultFail=  loanNum + " The Existing Loan Number entered does not    appear to be an active loan number.  Please confirm that the value was entered correctly! ";
         return tmpResultFail;


        }
        finally
        {
            cmdGetLoanNum.Connection.Close();
            cmdGetLoanNum.Dispose();
            myConnection.Dispose();
        }
```

MY java script:

```
    function loanCheckup() {

 // var txtLoanNum = document.getElementById('<%=LoanNumber.ClientID %>').value;

 var txtLoanNum = document.getElementById('LoanNumber').value;
//return Regex.IsMatch(txtLoanNum, "^-?\d*[0-9]?(|.\d*[0-9]|,\d*[0-9])?$");
  PageMethods.getRowValue(txtLoanNum, successLoan,failLoan);


}


 function successLoan(tmpResultPass) {

  alert(tmpResultPass);
 }


 function failLoan(tmpResultFail ) {

  alert(tmpResultFail);
 document.getElementById('LoanNumber').value = "";    
  }
```

Now when an exception is caught, tmpResultFail will appear, but the next line to clear the text field never gets executed.  I have script manager with  enable pagemethods = true. Everything works except clearing the textbox field. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The uncommented would surely not work because the client-side control doesn't have the same ID as the server-side one. If you look in the page source, your textbox is not called 'LoanNumber' anymore, so .getElementById() will not work.

The solution is either:

1. to use the ClientID property of your control, as you did in a javascript comment.
2. To use ASP.NET 4 ClientMode = "Static" to have a predictable client-side id.

Comment: I tried both suggestions, it did not work. Is there a better way to call code behind in javascript and not have it static. ? thanks in advance

Comment: There's maybe another error. Could you post a live page somewhere? Otherwise: what appears in the browser console? What is the reported JS error (if any)?